# If I Install AVG Security Suite, will it automatically Install the Toolbar & Search Engine?

Tags: windows, installation, avg-antivirus

Can I Install AVG without having it install the POS toolbar and search engine?

Comment: Try it and see, if it doesn't suit you then System Restore should get you back to where you were.

Answer (score 3):

No, a requirement for this type of advertisements is that the user may choose to not install the software. **You may have to look for the small print**, but there must be away to prevent the toolbar installation. Use the custom install (rather than the express install) option to see all the options.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of programs come with these sort of free addons nowadays and it is really quite annoying. However in nearly all cases you can pick advanced install mode (rather that auto or express) and then have an option to not install these things. This is definitely the case for AVG as I have installed it recently and it is also nearly the case for any other piece of software right now. Never express install!